# Unable to open flutter project in Xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode

After I created a flutter project in terminal using the command 'flutter create myapp' and try to open that project in Xcode, getting error message. However I am able to open the same project in VS code and Android Visual Studio.

[image]

Could someone help me to understand the reason of the error and how to sort it out?

I tried opening in Xcode using open existing project option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the iOS project within the flutter project can be opened with Xcode. Inside VSCode, right click on the iOS directory, and click "Open in Xcode".